# rspec install failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

screen:

E:\ir\InstantRails\rails_apps>gem install rspec

Attempting local installation of 'rspec'
Local gem file not found: rspec*.gem
Attempting remote installation of 'rspec'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    Could not find rspec (> 0) in the repository

my env: InstantRails 1.3a on windows

thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

successfully!

i reinstall the ruby using oneclick exe. then install rspec is ok.

problem is the instantrails's gem version is too old.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing it like this:

```
gem install rspec --source http://gems.github.com
```

Cheers

Comment: thanks，it seems not work too.

gems move to  RubyGems.org now. gems can be downloaded,can i install it locally?